# Building a Triangle with c++ loops

Tags: c++, loops

I am trying to build a triangle, with a user entered base and height.
When these entered values are different (base!=height), the program goes haywire and gets stuck in the triangle draw loop.

I've tried altering the code a couple of times, but please treat me as a programming novice.

```
//BUILD TRIANGLE//
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "\nEnter base and height:\n";
    int height{0}; int base{0};
    std::cin >> base >> height;

    std::string bottom(base, '*');
    std::string top = "*";
    int middlerows = height - 1;
    int middlespacechars;
    std::cout << top << std::endl;

    for (middlespacechars = 0; 
         middlerows != 1 || middlespacechars != base - 2; 
         ++middlespacechars, --middlerows) {

        std::string middlespace(middlespacechars, ' ');
        std::cout << "*" << middlespace << "*\n";
    }

    std::cout << bottom << "\n" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "^TRIANGLE\n";
    std::cout << "BASE = " << base << std::endl;
    std::cout << "HEIGHT = " << height << std::endl;
    std::cout << "goodbye" << "\n" << std::endl;
}
```

The output is totally haywire, with asterisks across the screen in no discernible shape.
When I put in values where base=height, though, a pretty little right angle triangle pops up.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude , please excuse the typo, the program was compiled with || .  I have edited the OP to reflect this.

Comment: https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/examples/pyramid-pattern#triangle.
You can take help from here.

Comment: Edit your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: @SidS All that's missing is definitions for base and height.  The goodbye var can be removed entirely for the purposes of this,

Comment: @osamakhalid I think my code might be a little different than the provided example due to the need to include blank space for the interior of the triangle.

Answer (score 2):

With your code, you can only draw well triangles which have `base` equal to `height`.

If you change stop condition in your `for` loop, you can get what you probably want to get:

```cpp
for (middlespacechars = 0; middlerows != 1 || middlespacechars != base - 2; ++middlespacechars, --middlerows) {

... into ...

for (middlespacechars = 0; middlerows > 1 || middlespacechars < base - 2; ++middlespacechars, --middlerows) {
```

It was huge probability that if `base` and `height` are different then stop condition will not be achieved. For loop in your code will stop if `middlerows` will be `1` and `middlespacechars` will be `base - 2` at the same moment.

Test it **[here](https://ideone.com/BU9SE9)**.

Comment: This edit seems to output a triangle with equal height and width even though inputs may be different.

Comment: @Kfkgy8392992 Yes, because your code doesn't allow for different `height` and `base` size proper display. For example if `height` will be `5` and `base` will be `10` so in next lines you should put `*` two places on right (not one) from previous one `*` (in above line). I only repair your `for` loop which has bug.

Comment: @Kfkgy8392992 With your code you can only draw icosceles triangles. If you want to display triangle with different `height` and `base` you need to calculate where to put `*` and where not put `*`.

Comment: I made an edit to only use one of the conditions to exit the loop (middlerows!=1).  This makes things work, and I know I'm not ascribing to KISS rn, but I'd like to find a way to line up the base with the hypotenuse (change the angle of the top arm so to say).  I see how that simply won't work with a base<height so I've finally accepted that I'll need to completely rewrite the triangle function.

Answer (score 0):

```
//C++ program to display hollow star pyramid

#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int rows, i, j, space;

   cout << "Enter number of rows: ";
   cin >> rows;

   for(i = 1; i <= rows; i++)
   {
      //for loop to put space in pyramid
      for (space = i; space < rows; space++)
         cout << " ";

      //for loop to print star
      for(j = 1; j <= (2 * rows - 1); j++)
      {
         if(i == rows || j == 1 || j == 2*i - 1)
            cout << "*";
         else
            cout << " ";
      }
      cout << "\n";
   }
   return 0;
}
```

[image: OUTPUT:]

Comment: I didn't mark this as the answer because it's a complete rewrite and I didn't want to scrap all my code,,,

Comment: it was just to use as a reference.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of why OP's code doesn't work.